# The Create method in a Comments controller is not working. Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I know similar questions have been asked for this subject and I have read all of them and was not able to figure out a clear solution. Before I state my problem, I will post all the required code.

The models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :scoreboard
  end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :scoreboards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Scoreboard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**The scoreboard is similar to a article page where users can post comments.**

The migration for the Comments:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.text :reply
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :scoreboard, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :comments, :users
    add_foreign_key :comments, :scoreboards
  end
end
```

The problem is with the **create** method in the **comments controller**. Here is the code for the method:

```
def create
     @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
     @comment.user_id = current_user.id
     @comment = @scoreboard.comments.build(comment_params)
     redirect_to scoreboard_url(@comment.scoreboard_id)
    end
```

The current_user method is located in a helper file in a separate folder. 
Whenever I submit the **form** for a new comment, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `user_id=' for nil:NilClass
```

One of the questions on stack stated that a user_id column is needed in comments, and when I tried migrating it said duplicated column cannot be created. Could it because there is a foreign key to users already present in the migration? What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite simple:

```
 @comment.user_id = current_user.id
 @comment = @scoreboard.comments.build(comment_params)
```

You're calling `@comment` without having defined it previously.

It *should* be like this:

```
 @comment = @scoreboard.comments.build comment_params
 @comment.user_id = current_user.id
```

---

> One of the questions on stack stated that a user_id column is needed in comments

To clarify, they were referring to the [`foreign_key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) of the `Comment` model.

You must remember that Rails is built on top of a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database):

[image]

Whichever variant of SQL you use, you'll still be using it in a *relational* manner; to which Rails has added the [ActiveRecord "object relational mapper"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#active-record-as-an-orm-framework).

Simply, this gives Rails the ability to call *associative* data with different queries etc. We don't see any of the technicalities; only the `@scoreboard.comments` association.

In the backend, Rails has to compute which data is related to the other. This can *only* happen when using appropriate relational database structures - including the use of `foreign_keys`.

This is why you have to assign the likes of `user_id` when creating associated objects. There is a trick to make it more succinct, though:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def create
     @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find params[:scoreboard_id]
     @comment    = @scoreboard.comments.build comment_params
   end

   private

   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:params).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
   end
end
```

Comment: The problem was exactly what you said. It's fixed now. Thank you!